# How to get Timestamp with AM/PM in java

Tags: java, datetime

I have a date as String , which needs to be converted in to Time Stamp with AM/PM . I tried the below way, I'm getting the proper date format but didn't get in AM/PM.

Can any one please help ?

code Snippet:

```
String dateString = "10/10/2010 11:23:29 AM";

SimpleDateFormat sfdate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss a");
    Date date = new Date();
    date = sfdate.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Which gives me the output as below :

```
2010-10-10 11:23:29.0
```

But I needs it like this

```
2010-10-10 11:23:29.00000000 AM
```

Kindly help me please.

Answer (score 3):

Why create a timestamp ? When you can just :

```
            SimpleDateFormat sfdate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss a");
            Date date = new Date();
            date = sfdate.parse(dateString);
            System.out.println(sfdate.format(date) );
```

Output:

```
10/10/10 11:23:29 AM
```

Comment: I dont need it in string, I need it as TimeStamp, as i have to insert that value in DB field which is defined as TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
System.out.println(sfdate.format(date));
```

As your last line rather than the one that you have at current.

Comment: I dont need it in string, I need it as TimeStamp, as i have to insert that value in DB field which is defined as TIMESTAMP

Comment: @muthukumar, actually a timestamp value is stored as a number of milliseconds since 1 jan 1970, so that is what you want to store in your database. All the rest is just a matter of representation. Just create a Timestamp and pass it to the DB.

Comment: You can send the string as formatted in to the SQL, or just send the raw milliseconds.  Specifics depend on the database type and schema, which you haven't supplied so hard to give you guidance on that one.

Answer (score 0):

[`Timestamp.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString%28%29) prints to a specific format: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff`.  The Timestamp object itself should be correct, if that's all you are looking for.

If you then want to define another format in order to print it as you like, that would require you to format `Date` object, using an appropriate pattern for the output format you are looking for.

Comment: okay.. Thanks for your suggestion. I thought it will not work. Let me try it out and get back to you. thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the result of `Timestamp.toString()`.  The actual *value* in the Timestamp object instance is valid.

If you're getting an error in a subsequent SQL operation, please post that error along with the code you're using.

Comment: oh.. I was not sure about that.. I'll check it and get back.Thank for your valuable suggestion

Comment: I have tried it. I have tried to convert this string 08/06/2013 12:08:00 AM to timeStamp and inserted into DB. But i saw it was inserted as PM instead of AM :( CAnu please help

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are using to do the update.